# Git repo inside another repo

Tags: php, git, github, yii, repository

I have directory structure which looks like that

[image]

Framework folder is from https://github.com/yiisoft/yii

For now, I'm updating framework folder like that.

Created another folder for Yii framework. Pulling every update and then duplicating framework directory into framework folder.

I want to automate this routine work. Is there anyway to update this framework folder from `https://github.com/yiisoft/yii` with commands like

```
cd framework
git pull
```

It might be wrong of course, but I'm newbie to git.
Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think git submodules would solve your problem: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use [Git Submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules):

> It often happens that while working on one project, you need to use another project from within it. Perhaps it’s a library that a third party developed or that you’re developing separately and using in multiple parent projects. A common issue arises in these scenarios: you want to be able to treat the two projects as separate yet still be able to use one from within the other.
>   ...
>   Git addresses this issue using submodules.

Here's a [wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/307/starting-your-yii-project-reference-guide-with-git-vcs-in-linux/) explaining how to manage it in Yii

Comment: I know about submodules, but I can't risk on production project. So need piece of code example from git pros

Comment: Set it up on your dev box to test. Sub modules are exactly what you're after

Comment: Never try on the production server! Even if git pros tell you how to do it, you should first try it on a dev environment!

Comment: +1 The yii link should answer this kind of workflow.